# Can't connect to the network

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, windows, help, connection

Windows 10 LTSC, Browser 11.5a4 (other versions have the same problem), time is synchronized, no antivirus, the firewall is disabled temporarily.

Log:

```
2/26/22, 19:55:40.740 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
2/26/22, 19:55:47.796 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/26/22, 19:55:47.796 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/26/22, 19:55:47.966 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
2/26/22, 19:55:48.969 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
2/26/22, 19:57:13.136 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host D3DA819E09D220BC8AA1C6C15B960DFD77707EFA at 73.116.0.92:9001)
2/26/22, 19:57:13.137 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
2/26/22, 19:57:13.137 [WARN] 9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
2/26/22, 19:57:13.182 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/26/22, 19:57:13.182 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
2/26/22, 19:57:13.370 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Log when using requested bridge:

```
2/26/22, 20:29:09.915 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
2/26/22, 20:29:28.844 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/26/22, 20:29:28.845 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/26/22, 20:29:28.845 [WARN] CreateProcessA() failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
2/26/22, 20:29:28.845 [WARN] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 0
2/26/22, 20:29:28.845 [WARN] Failed to start process: (null)     
2/26/22, 20:29:28.845 [WARN] Managed proxy at 'TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\obfs4proxy.exe' failed at launch.
2/26/22, 20:29:28.864 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
2/26/22, 20:29:29.113 [WARN] Can't use bridge at [scrubbed]: there is no configured transport called "obfs4". ...
2/26/22, 20:29:30.119 [WARN] Can't use bridge at [scrubbed]: there is no configured transport called "obfs4".
2/26/22, 20:30:57.541 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
```

Log when using snowflake:

```
2/26/22, 20:12:33.629 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
2/26/22, 20:12:39.453 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/26/22, 20:12:39.453 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/26/22, 20:12:39.454 [WARN] CreateProcessA() failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
2/26/22, 20:12:39.454 [WARN] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 0
2/26/22, 20:12:39.454 [WARN] Failed to start process: (null)
2/26/22, 20:12:39.454 [WARN] Managed proxy at 'TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\snowflake-client.exe' failed at launch.
2/26/22, 20:12:39.697 [WARN] Can't use bridge at [scrubbed]: there is no configured transport called "snowflake".
... [WARN] Can't use bridge at [scrubbed]: there is no configured transport called "snowflake".
2/26/22, 20:14:10.214 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying
```

known bridges again.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at these in your errors:

'TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\obfs4proxy.exe' failed at launch.
'TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\snowflake-client.exe' failed at launch.

Either something is wrong with your installation, in which case you should uninstall and reinstall Tor Browser or there is something in your OS that is keeping this from running.

Comment: A similar issue was reported here: https://forum.torproject.net/t/tor-browser-11-0-3-windows-10-os-cannot-use-bridge-to-connect/1424/8

Answer (score 0):

Well, speaking the things shortly - you've not understood the things under the hood and tried to ram them into the workflow. Now - in details.

1. A Snowflake is **not** a pluggable transport *itself*, it's a browser plugin allowing people who are **not** censored to share their connection. There's no specific "snowflake transport"
2. Your OBFS4 pluggable transport binary is not working - the error logs are clearly stating that. Grab a source and compile it by hand in GoLang locally - it is as easy as it sounds.
3. Using any spaces in directory names confuses Tor, so just make them DOS-like, I'm using it like `c:\\Tor\\...` it *just works*
4. Set a `LogLevel` to `debug` - yes, it produces a lot of text, but it really helps to troubleshoot things

If you need any further help - just drop me a line!